# Overwrite value in DB with a NULL using VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba

```
    If cell.Value <> "" Then

        uid = cell
        lname = Left(Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1), "'", ""), 50)
        fname = Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2), "'", "")
        stat = Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3), "'", "")
        role = Left(Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 4), "'", ""), 50)
        iqn = Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 5), "'", "")
        sdate = Format(Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 6), "'", ""), "yyyy-mm-dd")
        bdate = Format(Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 7), "'", ""), "yyyy-mm-dd")
        rodate = Format(Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 8), "'", ""), "yyyy-mm-dd")
        End If
        hirereason = Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 9), "'", "")
        roreason = Replace(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 10), "'", "")


        sql = "BEGIN TRAN IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WITH (updlock, serializable)"
        sql = sql & " WHERE UID = '" & uid & "')"
        sql = sql & " BEGIN"
        sql = sql & " UPDATE" & TableName
        sql = sql & " SET LName='" & lname & "', FName='" & fname & "'"
        sql = sql & ", Status='" & stat & "', Role='" & role & "'"
        sql = sql & ", IQNRole='" & iqn & "', StartDate='" & sdate & "'"
        sql = sql & ", BillableDate='" & bdate & "', RollOffDate='" & rodate & "'"
        sql = sql & ", HireReason='" & hirereason & "', RollOffReason='" & roreason & "'"
        sql = sql & " WHERE UID = '" & uid & "'"
        sql = sql & " END"
        sql = sql & " ELSE BEGIN"
        sql = sql & " INSERT " & TableName & " (UID, LName, FName, Status, Role, IQNRole, StartDate"
        sql = sql & ", BillableDate, RollOffDate, HireReason, RollOffReason)"
        sql = sql & " VALUES('" & uid & "', '" & lname & "', '" & fname & "', '" & stat & "'"
        sql = sql & ", '" & role & "', '" & iqn & "', '" & sdate & "', '" & bdate & "', '" & rodate & "'"
        sql = sql & ", '" & hirereason & "', '" & roreason & "')"
        sql = sql & " END COMMIT TRAN"

        Cn.Execute (sql)

    End If
```

I have some values and I'm formatting the date values which come is as string to date. If I run this as is it puts a default value for "" into the DB as 1900-1-1. I want the NULL values to actually stay in the DB and not be over-written. Furthermore I want them to update a cell with NULL if say it didn't use to be but now is.

I tried wrapping my value rodate in an IF statement and tried validating it against NULL, NOTHING, and EMPTY to say if it is one of these UPDATE DB with "NULL" but it doesn't do it. Date still comes out 1900-1-1. Any ideas?

Comment: You need more logic in your code to detect a blank date value and replace it with `null` (note: not `'null'`) instead of the formatted string value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, not sure if I get this question right.

The only thing I understood from it is that you are struggling with saving a date as NULL in the database. 
NULL and an empty string are not the same.
Try and see if this works:

```
dim vNull as variant 

vNull = Null 

if sDate = "" then 
    //Save vNull instead of Date
end if
```

I don't believe that you can capture NULL in a string datatype.

**Edit**
Perhaps stupid that I didn't think of this before, but instead of an empty string, can't you just put the string "NULL" in the query string?

Comment: I tried this and it shows up as NULL on the locals window under the value column however after I finish running macro and check DB the date is changed to default date from NULL.

Do you think the issue is on the update side rather than the variable?

Comment: Check edit. The query string is interpreted by SQL Server and I suppose that it should just understand the NULL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim roDate
'...
'...
rodate = Trim(cell.Offset(0, 8).Value)
If len(rodate)=0 Then
    rodate = null
else
    rodate = "'" & Format(rodate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
end if
'....
'....
'note no single quote here around rodate
sql = sql & ", BillableDate='" & bdate & "', RollOffDate=" & rodate
'...
'...
```